# Um toque para mais de um evento

Tags: java, android

Estou construindo um teclado musical, e estou com problema em fazer tocar o som da tecla seguinte se o usuário não tirar  o dedo da tela.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

```
 botao1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                posicao = 0;
                som.seekTo(posicao);
                som.start();
            }
}
```

Comment: Isso pode ajuda-lo. 
http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/08/multitouch-in-android.html

Comment: Achei tranquilo até aqui em aprender os multi-touch como eu poderia usar ele agora para ativar o mesmo ou outro evento?
Ou seja preciso acionar mais de uma tecla deslisando o dedo pela tela sem tirar  o mesmo.

Comment: Conseguiu a resposta que queria? Ou precisa de mais alguma coisa?

Comment: Ah sim consegui obrigado era para produzir este jogo https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.digital.onuse.xilofonenene

Answer (score 4):

Você pode explorar mais sobre **[Multi-touch Android](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=multi%20touch%20android)**, que está disponível desde o **Android 2.0** e foi melhorado na **versão 2.2**.

O `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` e `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP` são enviados a partir do segundo dedo. Para o primeiro dedo e `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` e `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` são utilizados.

O método `getPointerCount()` em `MotionEvent` permite determinar o número de indicações sobre o dispositivo. Todos os eventos e a posição dos ponteiros estão incluídos na instância de `MotionEvent` que você recebe no método `OnTouch()`.

Para acompanhar os eventos de toque a partir de várias dicas que você tem que usar os métodos `MotionEvent.getActionIndex()` e o `MotionEvent.getActionMasked()` para identificar o índice do ponteiro e o evento de toque que aconteceu para este ponteiro.

Este índice ponteiro pode mudar ao longo do tempo, caso um dedo é levantado a partir do dispositivo. Veja a imagem dos pontos pressionados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- `ACTION_DOWN` é para o primeiro dedo que toca a tela. Isso inicia o gesto. Os dados do apontador para este dedo está sempre no índice `0` na `MotionEvent`.
- `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` é para os dedos extras que entram no ecrã além da primeira. Os dados do apontador para este dedo é no índice retornado por `getActionIndex()`.
- `ACTION_POINTER_UP` é enviada quando o dedo deixa a tela, mas, pelo menos, um dedo é ainda tocá-lo. A última amostra de dados sobre o dedo que subiu está no índice retornado pelo `getActionIndex()`.
- `ACTION_UP` é enviada quando o último deixa o dedo tela. A última amostra de dados sobre o dedo que subiu está no índice `0`. Isto termina o gesto.
- `ACTION_CANCEL` significa todo o gesto foi abortada por algum motivo. Isto termina o gesto.

Detalhes

- [*Handling single and multi touch*](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html)
- [*Multitouch Tutorial*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_multitouch.htm)
- [*Making Sense of Multitouch*](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)